# Получение строки из имени идентификатора

Tags: c

У меня есть перечисление:

```
typedef enum
{
    STOP,
    PAUSE,
    RESUME,
    START
} COMMANDS;
```

Мне нужно выводить в логи для отладки строчное значение

```
STOP -> "STOP"
...
START -> "START"
```

Как установить соответствие, не прибегая к перебору switch (громоздко)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексация по массиву:

```
typedef enum
{
    STOP = 0,
    PAUSE,  // 1
    RESUME, // 2
    START   // 3
} COMMANDS;

char const* const strings[] = 
{
   "STOP",
   "PAUSE",
   "RESUME",
   "START"
};

char const* f(int idx)
{
   return strings[idx];
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", f(START));
}
```

Comment: Последнее время часто встречаю ошибку в проекте, когда изменяют увеличивают количество элементов перечисления, а вот изменить массив с именами забывают. Поэтому ввел дополнительную проверку в функцию f :-)

Answer (score 1):

Хорошее решение, всегда так делаю, впервые узнал об этом на http://www.quizful.net/post/enum-types-c.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить именно строку с названием идентификатора, то можно воспользоваться [макрооператором #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy090hkc).

Comment: Это только в VS2010 такая фича?

Comment: нет, это работает чуть ли не с начала девяностых.